# MiniZinc: Howto maximize a productivity var for each day of week

Tags: optimization, minizinc

I want to schedule staff members in a shop and maximize a productivity variable for each day in a week. This productivity var is computed as the target budget for a day divided by number of hours worked in this day.

My morking MiniZinc model is as follows.

Using "solve satisfy" works but doesn't optimize the number of hours or (personnel staff) depending on the target budget. For example I want to have less hours when the target bugget is small.

"solve maximize Productivity" doesn't work because it is an array.

Any idea?

---

```
include "globals.mzn";

% Week in year

int: Week = 41;

% Days in week

enum Days = {Mo, Tu, We, Th, Fr, Sa, Su};

% Employees

enum Employees = {E01, E02, E03, E04, E05, E06, E07, E08, E20, E21, E22, E23};

% Week contracts in hour

array[Employees] of int: Contracts = [35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 24, 24, 37, 40, 40, 40];

% Budget

array[Days] of int: Budget = [3500, 2500, 5000, 3500, 6000, 20000, 10000];

% Work hours

array[Employees, Days] of var 0..10: Work;

% Personnel effort

array[Days] of var int: Personnel_effort;

% Hour effort

array[Days] of var int: Hour_effort;

% Productivity

array[Days] of var int: Productivity;


% ===============================


% Constraints for the employees

% E01 can't work on We
% E01 work either on Sa or Su depending on Week odd or even

constraint forall (d in Days) (
 if d in {We} then Work[E01, d] = 0 endif
  /\
 if Week mod 2 = 0 then Work[E01, Su] = 0
 else Work[E01, Sa] = 0 endif
);

% E02 can't work on Sa

constraint forall (d in Days) (
  if d in {Sa} then Work[E02, d] = 0 endif
);

% E07 can't work on Tu, Wed, Th and Fr

constraint forall (d in Days) (
  if d in {Tu, We, Th, Fr} then Work[E07, d] = 0 endif
);

% E08 can't work on Mo, Tu, Wed and Th

constraint forall (d in Days) (
  if d in {Tu, We, Th, Fr} then Work[E08, d] = 0 endif
);

% For all employees minimum amount of hours by day is 7
% If employees are not off

constraint forall (e in Employees, d in Days) (
  if Work[e, d] != 0 then Work[e, d] >= 7 endif
);

% Employees with a Contract >= 35 must have exactly 2 days off

constraint forall (e in Employees) (
  if Contracts[e] >= 35 then exactly(2, Work[e, Days], 0) endif
);

% Employees must only work the amount of hours in their contract

constraint forall (e in Employees) (
  sum (d in Days) (Work[e,d]) = Contracts[e]
);

% Let's control the amount of employee's day off on We and Fr
% and Sa and Su

constraint forall (d in Days) (
  if d = Sa \/ d = Su then
    at_most(2, Work[Employees, d], 0)
  elseif d = We \/ d = Fr then
    at_most(3, Work[Employees, d], 0)
  else
    at_least(3, Work[Employees, d], 0)
  endif
);


% Personnel effort

constraint forall (d in Days) (
  Personnel_effort[d] = card(Employees) - among(Work[Employees, d], {0})
);

% Hour effort

constraint forall (d in Days) (
  Hour_effort[d] = (sum (e in Employees) (Work[e,d]))
  /\
  Hour_effort[d] >= 37 % (1m + 1e) and (1m + 2e)
);

% Productivity

constraint forall(d in Days) (
  Productivity[d] = (Budget[d] div Hour_effort[d])
   /\
  Productivity[d] > 40
);


% Solve

solve satisfy;
% solve maximize Productivity;


% Output

output [if d == Mo then show(Employees[e]) ++ "\t\t" else "" endif ++
    show(Days[d]) ++ ":" ++ show(Work[e,d]) ++
    if d == Su then "\n" else "\t" endif
    | e in Employees, d in Days ] ++
   [if d == Mo then "\nBudget\t\t" else "" endif ++
    show(Days[d]) ++ ":" ++ show(Budget[d]) ++ "\t"
    | d in Days ] ++
   [if d == Mo then "\nProd\t\t" else "" endif ++
    show(Days[d]) ++ ":" ++ show(Productivity[d]) ++ "\t"
    | d in Days ] ++
   [if d == Mo then "\nEffort (P)\t" else "" endif ++
    show(Days[d]) ++ ":" ++ show(Personnel_effort[d]) ++ "\t"
    | d in Days ] ++
   [if d == Mo then "\nEffort (h)\t" else "" endif ++
    show(Days[d]) ++ ":" ++ show(Hour_effort[d]) ++ "\t"
    | d in Days ];
```

Comment: `solve minimize` and `solve maximize` requires a single number, such as `sum(productivity)` (if that make sense). Can you formulate more specific what you want as a single number, then it's easier to help you.

Comment: With the above model and data and minizinc 2.2.0, for example, "solve satisfy" gives 8 persons and 68 hours on Mo for a budget of 3500 where on Th, for the same budget, I get 5 persons and 37 hours.  What I want to achieve, is to minimize the number of hours and persons allocated based on the budget (or maximize my "productivity" var but on each day individualy). As such, I would lke to get less persons and hours on Tu, than on Mo and Th. And the number of persons and hours on Mo and Th to be nearly the same. Hope this clarifies a bit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by hakank you need a single function to optimize. The most simple one is just to optimize over the sum of productivity:

```
solve maximize sum(d in Days) (Productivity[d]);
```

You might add more complex function if you wish.